# CopyIntoItemsLocal is not returning any results

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-services

I am trying to use CopyIntoItemsLocal to copy a text file from one folder to another one in the same sharepoint site location.

## Request

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <soap:CopyIntoItemsLocal>
         <soap:SourceUrl>http://sharepointserver/PartnerData/Notes/test.txt</soap:SourceUrl>
         <soap:DestinationUrls>
            <soap:string>http://sharepointserver/PartnerData/Notes/mynote/test.txt</soap:string>
         </soap:DestinationUrls>
      </soap:CopyIntoItemsLocal>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

## Response

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<soap:Body>
<CopyIntoItemsLocalResponse xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">
<CopyIntoItemsLocalResult>0</CopyIntoItemsLocalResult>
<Results/>
</CopyIntoItemsLocalResponse>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I don't see any error information in the response but the file was never copied. Also the results are empty. Is there anything missing from the request?

Comment: Does the "mynote" folder exist already?